# Continuar con la cuenta atrás cuando cierro la aplicacion

Tags: android

Mi aplicación tiene un `TextView` y un botón, cuando toco el botón comienza la cuenta atrás. El problema es que cuando cierro la aplicación y la vuelvo a abrir la cuenta atrás no sigue. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que continúe? Traté con `Shared`  `Preferences` pero solo guarda el valor final.

Mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu
    // this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void a(View view){
    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv1.setText("La cuenta llega a 0 en: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv1.setText("Listo!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Prueba sobreescribiendo el metodo `onPause()` y haciendo tu logica dentro de este metodo, si estas familiarizado con el ciclo de vida de las actividades este metodo se ejecuta cuando tu aplicación pasa a segundo plano.

Comment: cuando abres debe continuar en el ultimo valor antes de cerrar? te lo pregunto porque puedes seguir determinar el valor aunque hayas cerrado la aplicación.

Comment: ya ha pasado tiempo desde que hicieron la pregunta. El caso es que recién todo el tema y buscando información llegue aquí... y vi unos tutoriales, espero les sirvan para los que también al igual que yo recién tocan este tema: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZiUfnPgoTM http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que acabo de contestarte otra pregunta de cómo guardar un valor en `SharedPreferences`, así que espero que te sirvan las dos contestaciones. Te explico:

Para que la cuenta atrás de tu aplicación continué, aun estando la aplicación parada del todo complemente, es decir, que no salga cuando pulsas el botón donde salen todas las aplicaciones que se están ejecutando aunque no las tengas abiertas, debes de crear un [Service](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/) y puedes crear dos tipos de servicios:

> Un `Service` es `Started` (iniciado) cuando un componente de
>   aplicación (tal como una actividad) se inicia mediante una llamada
>   `startService()` . Una vez iniciado, un servicio puede ejecutarse en
>   segundo plano de forma indefinida, incluso si el componente que se
>   inició, se destruye. Por lo general, un servicio iniciado realiza una
>   sola operación y no devuelve un resultado a la persona que llama. Por
>   ejemplo, puede descargar o cargar un archivo a través de la red.
>   Cuando se realiza la operación, el servicio debe pararse.
>
> Un `Service` es `Bound` (ligado) cuando un componente de aplicación se
>   une a ella llamando a `bindService()` . Un servicio cota ofrece una
>   interfaz de cliente-servidor que permite que los componentes
>   interactúan con el servicio, envían solicitudes, obtener resultados, e
>   incluso lo hacen a través de procesos con la comunicación entre
>   procesos (IPC). Un servicio de cota se ejecuta sólo el tiempo que otro
>   componente de la aplicación está vinculada a la misma. Múltiples
>   componentes pueden unirse al servicio de una sola vez, pero cuando
>   todos ellos unbind, el servicio es destruido.

Es complicado entender al 100% los `Servicios`. Yo no los he conseguido dominar aún, pero te dejo unas guías con las que pude implementar mi primer `Service`:

- [Tutorial Para Crear Un Servicio En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/)
- [Ejemplo de Service en Android: Un cronometro](http://programandoointentandolo.com/2014/07/crear-service-en-android.html)

Además, combinando los `Services` con la clase `CountDownTimer` que sirve justo para crear una cuenta atrás, tendrás más que suficiente. Te explico esta clase:

Para que se ejecute necesitas el siguiente código:

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Con este código creamos un `CountDownTimer` que realiza una cuenta atrás de 20s (20000 milisegundos) y notifica cada segundo (1000 milisegundos). Esta clase necesita sobrescribir dos métodos:

- onTick: Este evento se invoca en cada intervalo de decrementación, es decir, cada segundo en este ejemplo.
- onFinish: Este  evento se invoca una vez que la cuenta atrás o el cronómetro inverso han acabado, se ha completado por tanto el tiempo total de 20 segundos del ejemplo.

Lo de los `Services` es un poco lioso, ya te lo digo, pero espero que combinando esto, puedas conseguir lo que necesitas.

Suerte y si necesitas cualquier cosa, deja un comentario.

¡¡Suerte con tu App!!

Answer (score 0):

En el `onCrate()` agrega esto

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    tv1.setText("La cuenta llega a 0 en: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    tv1.setText("Listo!");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

Y elimina el método `a(View view)`

Si eso no funciona, agrega a la pregunta tu layout `activity_main` para tener el panorama completo.